# Numbers and the period of their inverse

Tags: fractions, periodic-functions

I am currently investigating the correlation between a natural number and the length of its inverse's period. For example:

$$
\frac{1}{3760} = 0.00026595744680851063829787234042553191489361702127\ (period\ 46) \\
\frac{1}{1122} = 0.00089126559714795\ (period\ 16)
$$
And so on.
There is a simple explanation for why does this happen mixing powers and modular arithmetic but it's just an iterative process, which is troublesome for really big numbers.

`Which conjectures, theories, hypothesis exists regarding the computation of the periodic length of any natural number's inverse?`

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: I (not the OP) would say $1$; it's $0.25000\ldots$

Comment: Let's just assume that a few numbers in (0,10) are special

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}$ will have it's repetend length be some divisor of Euler's Totient Function $\phi(n)$.  Some times it will be $\phi(n)$ itself such as for $\frac{1}{65537}$ which has repetend length $\phi(65537)=65536$.  Other times it will be less than that such as $\frac{1}{13}$ which has repetend length $6$ which is a divisor of $\phi(13)=12$

Comment: @TonyK that's interesting, let me check

Comment: loko, I think you replied to the wrong person :-)

Comment: Additionally, assuming $n$ is coprime to $10$ one can show that the repetend length will be the multiplicative order of $10$ in $\Bbb Z_{n}$.  Both of these follow from [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Comment: @JMoravitz: ...and if $n$ is not coprime to $10$, you can just divide out all the $2$'s and $5$'s. So the OP's examples reduce to $n=47$ and $n=561$. (And we find than $10^{46}\equiv 1\bmod 47$, and $10^{16}\equiv 1\bmod 561$; and that these are the smallest such exponents. Note that $46$ divides $\phi(47)=46$, and $16$ divides $\phi(561)=320$.)

Comment: Some bibliography https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S031508600800092X

Comment: @JMoravitz Euler's Totient Function seems very interesting for my research, thank you very much.

Comment: The associated formulas are in https://oeis.org/A007732 .